# How to order multidimensional arrays PHP

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, sorting, object

I've been stuck for hours in trying to order `get_pages()` object from wordpress.

I need to order the pages by `menu_order` (`get_pages->menu_order`);

I've been trying several PHP functions but none worked in such purpose.

**PHP**

```
foreach(get_pages(pll_current_language()) as $page) { 

    // Somewhere here each page should go up/down in order to be DESC/ASC

    $template = get_post_meta( $page->ID, '_wp_page_template', true ); 
    include_once($template);  

}
```

My question is, How can I order this object by one of its values,
**example**:

**I want to order get_pages() by get_pages()->menu_order**

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: just using the `$args` options from the docs ? https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_pages

Comment: Thanks @DiegoMariani, It worked so sweet. I should be checking for docs more often. All the best mate :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just use the `$args` options array and set the `sort_order`, `sort_column` on whatever you need, **check the docs** https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_pages

```
$args = [
    'sort_order' => 'asc',
    'sort_column' => 'menu_order'
];

$pages = get_pages($args);
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use the [`usort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) function. You provide it with a comparison function (in your case a function that compares `$a->menu_order` to `$b->menu_order`) and it will then use it to sort the elements in your array.

Comment: Take a look at @DiegoMariani's comment first. It might be you don't even need to do the sort in PHP.

Comment: Yes @Chris I tried that and it worked, however thanks for your answer